# jquery mobile fixed footer scrolls with the page

Tags: jquery-mobile

I'm trying to implement the fixed footer on my site.

My problem is, when I scroll the page, the footer is overlapping with the content. When scrolling is finished, it falls back to the bottom. Is this the standard behavior?

[I checked this link](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed.html). It works on desktop browser. ie. the footer remains fixed on scrolling. But on mobile(android) it scrolls with the page. Can I make it really fixed?

EDIT:  HTML added

```html
<div data-role="footer" data-iconpos="left"  data-id="jefooter" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/welcome" data-icon="jehome" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" data-ajax="false">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/mobile/users/settings" id="user_auth" data-icon="jesettings" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="fade" data-ajax="false">My Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/mobile/help" data-icon="jehelp" data-iconpos="notext" data-transition="fade" data-ajax="false">Help</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see the page at m.qa.hungryzone.com

EDIT 2:

Android version is 2.3.5

Comment: Can you post the HTML for your footer. If possible, both before and after rendered by Jquery. Also, what version of android?

Comment: @Jeemusu, I have added details

Comment: Is it a Galaxy by any chance?

Comment: Your markup is absolutely fine, which leads me to believe it's probably a bug. I remember reading somewhere that 2.3.5 on some galaxys had problems with fixed footers in jQuery. Hence my question above. I would probably report it as a bug on the jQuery Mobile site, and see if you get a reply.

Comment: A quick search of the jquery bug site brought this up: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4281

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this appears to be a bug that is present with jQuery Mobile on devices running Android 2.3.5 - 2.3.6 .

The guys at jQuery Mobile are pointing the finger at Google:

> ...this does seem to be a bit of blip -- a regression in Android that Google seems to be fixing in later versions but as all Android issues go, it's not clear or consistent.

The open bug report and more details can be found here:
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/4281

Answer (score 8):

I fixed it by replacing

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

with

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no,width=device-width" />
```

in the header of the html

and by adding a new class to the footers along with data-role='footer'

```
.footer {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of jQuery Mobile?  It's still not perfect, but is better than older versions.  This is the latest (1.2.0 alpha)...

http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2012/08/01/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-2-0-alpha/#download

**EDIT**

You could stop using the jQuery Mobile fixed footer and add this class instead to your footer:

```
.custom-fixed-footer {
position: fixed !important;
left: 0px !important;
right: 0px !important;
bottom: 0px !important;
z-index: 999 !important;
}
```